# How can I add a code to copy the first line of excel sheet and paste it on new email body

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

The Code below copies the selection that I choose from an excel sheet and pastes it to a new email body and adds a signature, but I need it to also add the first row(Range("A1:O1")) to the email body above the selection that it pastes and that it will save the Range Width, Height, Format...

```
Sub SendSelectedCells_inOutlookEmail()
Dim objSelection As Excel.Range
Dim objTempWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim objTempWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim strTempHTMLFile As String
Dim objTempHTMLFile As Object
Dim objFileSystem As Object
Dim objTextStream As Object
Dim objOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNewEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strSig As String

'Copy the selection
Set objSelection = Selection
Selection.Copy

'Paste the copied selected ranges into a temp worksheet
Set objTempWorkbook = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
Set objTempWorksheet = objTempWorkbook.Sheets(1)

'Keep the values, column widths and formats in pasting
With objTempWorksheet.Cells(1)
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With

'Save the temp worksheet as a HTML file
Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strTempHTMLFile = objFileSystem.GetSpecialFolder(2).Path & "\Temp for Excel" & Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD hh-mm-ss") & ".htm"
Set objTempHTMLFile = objTempWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, strTempHTMLFile, objTempWorksheet.Name, objTempWorksheet.UsedRange.Address)
objTempHTMLFile.Publish (True)

'Create a new email
Set objOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNewEmail = objOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'Read the HTML file data and insert into the email body
Set objTextStream = objFileSystem.OpenTextFile(strTempHTMLFile)
objNewEmail.Display
strSig = objNewEmail.HTMLBody
objNewEmail.HTMLBody = objTextStream.ReadAll & strSig

'You can specify the new email recipients, subjects here using the following lines:
'objNewEmail.To = "johnsmith@datanumen.com"
'objNewEmail.Subject = "DataNumen Products"
'objNewEmail.Send --> directly send out this email

objTextStream.Close
objTempWorkbook.Close (False)
objFileSystem.DeleteFile (strTempHTMLFile)
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly copy the headers before copying the selection and pasting below

```
Dim dblRH as Double

Set objSelection = Selection
'Copy Headers
dblRH = Rows(1).RowHeight
Range("A1:O1").Copy

'Paste the copied selected ranges into a temp worksheet
Set objTempWorkbook = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
Set objTempWorksheet = objTempWorkbook.Sheets(1)

'Keep the values, column widths and formats in pasting
With objTempWorksheet.Cells(1)
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
     .RowHeight = dblRH
End With

'Copy Selection
objSelection.Copy

With objTempWorksheet.Range("A2")
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With
```

Comment: it works thanks!
also, if I want to save the RowHeight of the header what code do I need to add?

Comment: I get 'Sub or Function not defined' on 'Row' in dblRH = Row(1).RowHeight

Comment: Change Row(1) to Rows(1)

Comment: Thanks a lot man!! you really helped me out :)